# Ruby on Rails - Checking against HTTP errors in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just today I've found my fbgraph implementation has started returning a 400 Bad Request error which is causing an internal server error.

The controller looks like:

```
def fb
    fbclient = FBGraph::Client.new(:client_id => 'ID', :secret_id => 'SECRET')
    @fbname = fbclient.selection.user('129220333799040').feed.info!['data'][0].from.name
    @fbmessage = fbclient.selection.user('129220333799040').feed.info!['data'][0].message
end
```

How can I check before calling @fbname in my view that I've received a 200 status?

Thanks.

Update: following Devin M's suggestion, I've switched the above action to

```
def fb
        fbclient = FBGraph::Client.new(:client_id => 'ID', :secret_id => 'SECRET')
        begin
            @fbname = fbclient.selection.user('129220333799040').feed.info!['data'][0].from.name
            @fbmessage = fbclient.selection.user('129220333799040').feed.info!['data'][0].message
        rescue
            @fbname = "Facebook Account"
            @fbmessage = "Facebook's API is a nightmare"
        end
    end
```

Comment: i think you should check first if you got the user right(fbclient.selection.user('129220333799040')) there are too many chains on your call that might bring about a nil or a 400 bad request. try doing it step by step and add the appropriate check when you find which returns the 400

Comment: @corroded - thanks.  It seems the api may have changed.  I can still access the user, but trying to access the user's feed results in the 400 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should write some tests for this, Its hard to work with Facebooks nightmare of an API.
Although if you wanted to catch this error try using that way you can catch the specific error and take some action on it in the rescue portion.

```
begin
rescue
end
```

If you want me to take a look at the docs and see what you should catch let me know.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, this works.  I was trying to use rescue_from, but that was failing. I have no idea why the sudden errors.   It was working as recently as 2 days ago, and a different application is able to use very similar code without an error now... i'll edit my question with what I've used

Comment: No problem, Facebook is tough to program against.